# Objective C: After I set property to a value, when I check in debugger, it is still nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a property that I am initializing in viewDidLoad, that is declared in my header file.  In viewDidLoad I declare it here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

viewControllerList = [NSMutableArray new];

vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"moreSpeedyCafeViewController"];

[self loadDefaults];

self.dataSource = self;
```

In the loadDefaults method, I am iterating through an array and setting its properties.  As I step through in the debugger, the values are nil even after being set.  The values in the dictionary are not nil, I have checked that.  I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *newDict in array) {
        tempDict = newDict;
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[tempDict objectForKey:@"ImageUrls"]objectAtIndex:0]]];
        vc.dmsImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        vc.dmsDescriptionLabel.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Title"];
        vc.dmsLinkText.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"LinkText"];
        vc.index = [array indexOfObject:tempDict];

        [viewControllerList addObject:vc];
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are setting the properties of `vc`, adding `vc` to an array, and every subsequent iteration you are resetting the properties of that same `vc` instance, and re-adding the same view controller to the array again and and again.

Comment: Setting that aside, there could also be dictionary issues that we can't possibly diagnose on the basis of the information provided (e.g. we'd need to see a print out of `tempDict`). Also, there are completely unrelated issues with this code (e.g. why are you building an array of view controllers at all? why are you loading images up front, versus lazily? why are you retrieving images synchronously?), but I wouldn't worry about those until you fix your current problem.

Comment: Well, much of the code I have not submitted here due to its content for personal reasons, so I submitted what I could.  But essentially, this code is being handle in an asynchronous data call.

This call is in a PageViewController, hence the reason for adding the view controllers to an array for that purpose.  The contents of the dictionary are valid, and all the keys contain their proper values.  I am able to NSLog them  all successfully.

And I know I need to reset vc to a new instance every time in the loop because I am going to be reusing the same view controller n number of times.